# Triangle entities like ▶ cannot display properly in Safari

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari, frontend

I meant to use triangle entities ▶ and ◀ in my website as indicating arrows. It appears normal on Chrome OSX in simulation mode.

**Desktop**:

[image]

But it doesn't display properly at mobile end.

**Mobile**:

[image]

Is this some sort of default setting? How can I modify?

Comment: I hope that's a stock image and you're not actually selling drop ship kittens in an app/website.

Comment: may be media queries issue

Answer (score 1):

if you are using HTML Code or Unicode Hexadecimal arrows,
different browsers interpret differently that kind of code and they have different default settings, so probably the best way to get it working could be to use an image instead.

Answer (score 0):

I always use CSS to create solid color triangles when needed:

```css
div.triangle {
  position: relative;
}
div.triangle::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-color: transparent red transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

Just use more CSS to place the triangle div as per your requirements.

Comment: I knew this kind of solution. But I needed to apply a box shadow onto the triangles in this scenario. CSS triangles will have square box shadows which is just bizarre.